# which state is better to exclude NULL as well as spaces while querying the data from hive table

Tags: mysql, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out which one the below is better while selecting data from my source table to target table so all NULLS are replaced by '' and there are no spaces in string. is there any difference or both are same

```
TRIM(NVL(col1,''))
```

OR :

```
NVL(TRIM(col1),'')
```

Comment: nvl(col1, '') alone should do the job, no need of trim function on top of that

Answer (score 0):

Those two expressions are functionaly equivalent.

Expression `TRIM(NVL(col1,''))` :

- when `col1` contains spaces, `NVL` returns it unchanged and the outer `trim` remove spaces
- when `col1` is `NULL`, `NVL` returns `''`, which `trim` returns unchanged

Expression `NVL(TRIM(col1),'')` :

- when `col1` contains spaces, `TRIM` removes them and the outr `NVL` leaves the result unchanged
- when `col1` is `NULL`, `TRIM` returns `NULL`, that `NVL` turns into `''`